# Managing Fragments: Hide and Show

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I know there is a lot of questions about fragments but I have some doubts.

I have some activities showing up multiple fragments. I have done my own fragment manager to control them and it worked very well until I had to hide and show some fragments to reuse them for another issues.

[image]

My problem is when I go back from fragment B to Activity 1 this is what I do

```
 fun hidePaymentsBackStack(manager: FragmentManager) {
        for (fragment in manager.fragments) {
            if (fragment !is PaymentsFragment) {
                manager.beginTransaction().hide(fragment).commit()
            }
        }
    }
```

go through the stack of fragments shown in Activity 1 and hide them instead of the first one on top of the activity.

If I add Fragment C it's all ok but when I add Fragment A again is not shown on top of the last one. If I remove the fragments instead of showing when I call 
MyFragmentManager.add()...  manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) is not null and I thought removing them should completely remove the fragment, it enters in showFragment() and when I do transaction.show never appears on top.

This is part of the important code. I am missing something?

```
fun add(manager: FragmentManager, fragmentTag: String, container: Int) {
        var fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)
        if (fragment != null) {
            showFragment(manager, fragment)
        } else {
            addFragment(manager, getFragment(fragmentTag, manager)!!, container, fragmentTag)
        }
    }


   private fun addFragment(manager: FragmentManager, fragment: Fragment, container: Int, fragmentTag: String) {
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.add(container, fragment, fragmentTag)
        transaction.commit()
    }

private fun showFragment(fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
                             fragment: Fragment) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack()
        val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.show(fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }


private fun removeFragment(manager: FragmentManager,
                               fragment: Fragment) {
        val trans = manager.beginTransaction()
        trans.remove(fragment)
        trans.commit()
        manager.popBackStack()
    }

 fun removePaymentsBackStack(manager: FragmentManager) {
        for (fragment in manager.fragments) {
            if (fragment !is PaymentsFragment) {
                manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()
                manager.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help to show again this fragments.

Thank you!!